Spring boot Can I create a new service class for checking user's authority?
In my application, multiple service classes require the same method to check the logged-in user's role and retrieve certain information based on that user's information.
I'm using this method instead of @PreAuthorize because some parameters depend on the role.
Currently, I've implemented this method in each service class, resulting in code duplication.
To improve maintainability and reduce duplication, I'm considering creating a separate class.
Is this a recommended approach, and are there any alternative strategies for handling this scenario more effectively?
private AdminUserSearchDto updateSearchInformation(CustomUserDetails userDetails, Long classroomId, Integer year)
{
    if(Role.TEACHER.getValue().equals(userDetails.getRole()))
    {
        classroomId = classroomService.findClassroomByAdminUserId(userDetails.getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new GlobalException(ExceptionMessage.TEACHER_NOT_ASSIGNED))
                .getId();
        year = DataUtilService.getYearData();

    }
    return AdminUserSearchDto.builder()
            .classroomId(classroomId)
            .year(year)
            .build();
}

I would appreciate if you could guide me a better design.

Why are you doing this, that is what Spring Security does for you with @PreAuthorize no need to write your own.

If the role is Teacher, then the information is changed to their own class. I'm aware of @PreAuthrize.
